# Calculating the size in bytes of HTTP Request Post

Tags: html, json, jmeter, html-post

I am using JMeter to test a http server and sending in different sizes of load in the Body. I am posting content-type JSON Object and send very big files, and sometimes small.

In the request, the content-length varies accordingly to what I set but for whatever reason, the Size in bytes is always 277 regardless of the size of the json object and the varying values for content-length. Why isn't the size in bytes changing along with the change in size of the body that is being sent?
This is messing up the KB/sec value that is being calculated in Jmeter because the number of bytes per message is showing 277 every time even though the body is changing.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how I can calculate the actual KB/Sec being sent

Answer (score 0):

I've never faced with same case in JMeter, but when I recently ran my JMeter script in the [load testing cloud](http://blazemeter.com), I noticed that Kb/s value was look like real. 
[image]